# How to populate/fill ChoiceField with custom values in Django Forms

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have been trying to make a Form for item removal but I don't know how to connect the field to the model, here's what I'm doing:

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    queryset = Student.objects.filter().values('name')
    choices = [('', var) for var in queryset]
    names = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices)

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = '__all__'
```

I used this class to connect to the Student model and use its fields, however I want to add a field of my own to it, which is `names = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices)`, but what I want to know is, how would I connect this field that lists all names, for example, to the form to make it so that I could pick an object's name and then I could change/delete it accordingly?

```
class StudentRegister(generic.FormView):
    template_name = 'students/student_form.html'
    form_class = StudentForm
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save(commit=True)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

This is my views.py and as you can see, it automatically sets the values of the form because those are already "tied in" to a model field, but not the choice field I added. How would I correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Approach using queryset

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.ChoiceField(queryset=Student.objects.all())

    or

    name = forms.ChoiceField([("%s" % stud['id'], "%s" % stud['name']) for stud in
                       Student.objects.all().values('id', 'name')])


class Student(models.Model):

    # existing fields comes here

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

2) Dynamic load using ajax

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.ChoiceField()


class Student(models.Model):

    # existing fields comes here

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Load data using ajax

```
<script>
(function($){

//get your data
function get_data(){
    $("#<id_of_choice_field>").empty();
        $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<url_for_getting_data>",
            data: { "csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}" },
            cache: false,
            success: function(json) {
                if (json) {
                    for (var source in json) {
                       $("#id_of_choice_field").prepend("<option value='"+json[source].id+"'>"+json[source].name+"</option>");
                    }

                }
            }
        });
    $("#id_of_choice_field").prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'>--------------</option>");
}
get_data();

}(django.jQuery));
</script>
```

AJAX URL & method

```
url(r'^get-all-student/$', get_all_student)

def get_all_student(request):
    """

    :param request:
    :return:
    """
    if request.method == "POST" and request.is_ajax():
        all_student = []
        for student in Student.objects.all().values('id', 'name'):
            all_student.append({'id': student['id'], 'name': student['name']})
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(all_student), content_type="application/json")
    return HttpResponseNotAllowed(['GET'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass all the names to a single field with:

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Student.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = '__all__'
```

and let your Student model return the name:

```
class Student(models.Model):

    # Model fields

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

You can look for more ways for your forms to interact with models at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields